# JSON array coming as json object if no data in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-json, android-parser

I am getting JSON response from the API call. But in that response one of the JSONArray is coming as JSONObject if there is no data as given below.  Without data : `"InbuildData": null.`
With data :`"InbuildData": [{"value": "Yes","checkStatus":0}]`. Anyone please suggest better option to identify this situation!

Answer (score 0):

Not user about your confusion this is a simple case you can handle this like this in your model

```
 @SerializedName("InbuildDataItem")
var inBuildDataItem:InbuildDataItem?=null
data class InbuildDataItem(
    @SerializedName("checkStatus")
    val checkStatus: Int,
    @SerializedName("value")
    val value: String
)
```

Before using check if inBuildDataItem is null or not